# how to detect activity indicator when stop?

Tags: xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

Is there any way to detect when indicator is stopped?
I want to access to specific method when indicator is stopped successfully.
Please someone tell me how to detect it.

Thanks.

Comment: You would normally do it the other way around. Call stop indicator whenever you are done with whatever you are doing.

Comment: You can put your code after `[yourindicatorname stopAnimatting];` method.

Comment: yes, I will, but I want to detect when the stop code is called.

Comment: I actually want to stop application until get some info from connection delegate method. I'm gonna input the stop code in the delegate method, but main view controller doesn't know the indicator is stopped or animating from delegate method in other file.

Answer (score 0):

You're in charge of any activity indicators that you create -- if you tell them to stop, they stop. Conversely, they won't stop until you stop them. There's no need to *detect* that the indicator is stopped -- you *decide* when you want it to stop.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but As I said in the comment in above, I need to make stop the indicator in the delegate method, and I'm using at least 3 diffrent delegate methods. (one is http connection, another is stream and the last is accelerometer.) I get IP address from the http connection delegate and, using the address connect to the TCP server. I want to stop the indicator in the stream delegate method and I will input the stop code in there. the problem is mainviewcontroller and stream method is in the diffrent file, so mainview doesn't know the indicator is stopped.

Comment: Your view controller should be in charge of its views -- other objects shouldn't go messing with them. If some other object wants the view controllers activity indicator stopped, they should ask the view controller to stop it, not stop it directly.

Comment: So, I make the indicator in the AppDelegate.h file. I think it can stop the indicator. Then, Could you let me know how can I change the main view from the delegate method in other file??